# Trix editor with livewire and alpine

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

So i have a working trix editor i can store it to database no problems with that.

But i have 2 issues.
problem 1
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'loadHTML')
problem 2
data is not loaded in the editor using wire model.

For problem 1 i found solution to remove the warnings but data is not being loaded :

```
        setValue() { if(this.$refs.trix.editor) this.$refs.trix.editor.loadHTML(this.value) },
```

For the second problem if i use a cdn like this it all works no errors no loading data problems so is there a problem in my code or is it my app.js what can i do to fix this? :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.1/trix.min.js"></script>
```

**App.js**

```
import Trix from "trix";
window.Trix = Trix;
import './bootstrap';
import moment from "moment";
import Pikaday from 'pikaday';
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
moment().format();
window.moment = moment;
window.Pikaday = Pikaday;
window.Alpine = Alpine;
Alpine.start();
```

**component**

```
<div
class="rounded-md shadow-sm"
x-data="{
    value: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')),
    isFocused() { return document.activeElement !== this.$refs.trix },
 {{-- setValue() { this.$refs.trix.editor.loadHTML(this.value) },--}}
    setValue() { if(this.$refs.trix.editor) this.$refs.trix.editor.loadHTML(this.value) },
}"
x-init="setValue(); $watch('value', () => isFocused() && setValue())"
x-on:trix-change="value = $event.target.value"
{{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }}
wire:ignore>
<input id="x" type="hidden">
<trix-editor x-ref="trix" input="x" class="trix-editor form-textarea block w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"></trix-editor>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself like this :

```
<div
class="rounded-md shadow-sm"
x-data="{
    value: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')),
    isFocused() { return document.activeElement !== this.$refs.trix },
    setValue() { if(this.$refs.trix.editor) this.$refs.trix.editor.loadHTML(this.value) },
}"
x-init="setValue(); $watch('value', () => isFocused() && setValue())"
x-on:trix-change="value = $event.target.value"
{{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }}
wire:ignore>
<input id="body" value="{!!  $value !!}" type="hidden">
<trix-editor x-ref="trix" input="body" class="trix-editor form-textarea block w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"></trix-editor>
```

And where you want to use it :

```
<x-input.rich-text wire:model.defer="body" value="{{ $body }}" id="about"/>
```

Comment: Nice I was stuck at the exact same place. Great work